# Fetching record from two table and convert into json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I'm new in PHP and trying to get the below response using php sql but i'm not be able to find the such desire output

```
[{"Id":1, "name": "India", "Cities":[{"Id":1, "Name":"Mumbai", "country_id":1}, {"Id":2,"Name":"Delhi","country_id":1},
"id":3,"Name":Banglore","country_id":1}, {"Id":2, "Name":"USA", "Cities":[{"Id":6, "Name":"New York", "country_id":2},.....
```

I have two tables one is country based and other is city based.

```
I tried
<?php

    include_once("config.inc.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
    $sqlCity = "SELECT * FROM city";

    $cityQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCity);
    $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $mainArray = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($cityQuery) > 0 ){
        $cityResponse = array();
        while($resCity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cityQuery)){
            $cityResponse[] = $resCity;
        }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery) > 0 ){
        $response = array();
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){
            $response[] = $res;
        }
        foreach($cityResponse as $city){
            foreach($response as $country){
                if($city['country_id'] == $country['id']){

                    $mainArray = array("Cities" => $city);
                }
            }
        }
        echo '{"response": '.json_encode($response).', '.json_encode($mainArray).' "success": true}';
    }
    }else{
        echo '{"response": '.json_encode($response).' "success": false}';
    }


?>
```

currently my response showing

```
{"response": [{"id":"1","name":"India"},{"id":"2","name":"USA"},{"id":"3","name":"UK"}], {"Cities":{"id":"15","name":"Manchester","country_id":"3"}} "success": true}
```

Comment: but what you want to do next??

Comment: just want json format data

Comment: I guess you've got a script that's reading the response your echo'ing out? What does that script look like? Because otherwise you have the exact thing you're looking for before you wrap it in `{"response": ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For detail code explanation check the inline comments

- Modify the SQL query with related column names
- The memory you have to take care. By default memory limit in php is 128MB in 5.3
- Check the code and let me know the result

  ```
  <?php

  $data = array();

  //include your database configuration files
  include_once("config.inc.php");

  //execute the join query to fetch the result
  $sql = "SELECT country.country_id, country.name AS country_name,".
  " city.city_id, city.name AS city_name FROM country ".
  " JOIN city ON city.country_id=country.country_id ".
  " ORDER BY country.country_id ";

  //execute query
  $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('error exists on select query');

  //check the number of rows count
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery) > 0 ){

  //country id temprory array
  $country_id = array();

  //loop each result
  while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){

      //check the country id is already exist the only push the city entries
      if(!in_array($result['country_id'],$country_id)) {

          //if the city is for new country then add it to the main container
          if(isset($entry) && !empty($entry)) {
              array_push($data, $entry);
          }

          //create entry array
          $entry = array();   
          $entry['Id'] = $result['country_id'];
          $entry['name'] = $result['country_name'];
          $entry['Cities'] = array();

          //create cities array
          $city = array();
          $city['Id'] = $result['city_id'];
          $city['name'] = $result['city_name'];
          $city['country_id'] = $result['country_id'];

          //append city entry
          array_push($entry['Cities'], $city);
          $country_id[] = $result['country_id'];
      }
      else {

          //create and append city entry only
          $city = array();
          $city['Id'] = $result['city_id'];
          $city['name'] = $result['city_name'];
          $city['country_id'] = $result['country_id'];
          array_push($entry['Cities'], $city);
      }

  }

  }
      //display and check the expected results
              echo json_encode($data);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<?php

    include_once("config.inc.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
    $sqlCity = "SELECT * FROM city";

    $cityQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCity);
    $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $mainArray = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($cityQuery) > 0 ){
        $cityResponse = array();
        while($resCity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cityQuery)){
            $cityResponse[] = $resCity;
        }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery) > 0 ){
        $response = array();
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){
            $response[] = $res;
        }
        foreach($cityResponse as $city){
            foreach($response as $country){
                if($city['country_id'] == $country['id']){

                    $mainArray = array("Cities" => $city);
                }
            }
        }

        echo json_encode(array('result'=>'true','Cities'=>$mainArray));
    }
    }else{

         echo json_encode(array('result'=>'false','Cities'=>$response));
    }


?>
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong into code currently response showing me {"response": [{"id":"1","name":"India"},{"id":"2","name":"USA"},{"id":"3","name":"UK"}], {"Cities":{"id":"15","name":"Manchester","country_id":"3"}} "success": true}

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this. It actually works for me and it's cool. You can extend to 3 or more tables by editing the code.

```
try {

    $results = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM country";
    $values = array();

    $stmt = $datab->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($values);

    while($country = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $cities = null;

        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE country_id = ?" ;
        $values2 = array($country['id']);

        $stmt2 = $datab->prepare($query2);
        $stmt2->execute($values2);
        $cities = $stmt2->fetchAll();

        if($cities){
            $country['cities'] = $cities;
        } else {
            $country['cities'] = '';
        }

        array_push($results, $country);  
    }

    echo json_encode(array("Countries" => $results));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
}
```